# Avoid flexbox to expand with CSS when element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two Div's next to each other, wrapped in a container Div which has the `display:flex`-attribute. Now I have this kind of tricky issue where I need to be able to click on one element inside the div which then shows a previously hidden div, which also is placed inside the container. When the hidden div is visible, the container of course expands BUT I need the container NOT to expand and I cannot place the hidden div outside the container. I have the following example code:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="top">
        This is the top
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        This is the bottom - click me
    </div>
    <div class="expand">
        This is hidden content
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="content right">
     This is the right content
 </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
  border: 1px solid;
 }

.top, .bottom {
  height:100px;
 }

.top {
  background: #ddd;
 }

.bottom {
  background: #eee;
 }

.right {
  background: #e9e9e9
 }

.expand {
  display:none;
  background: #999;
 }
```

I have made [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pgpa4ekz/1/) - So the hidden div should be outside the container when its visible - can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding `position: absolute;` to the `.expand` div pushes the div outside of the box

https://jsfiddle.net/4724m90k/